# Why can't I see my neon-animeted tags, moving/fading-out/etc.?

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

The code is working properly, but somehow it does not show any animations.

I mean using fade-out-animation, it only disappears, no matter what is the duration.

I've imported all the stuff I needed (fade-out-animation,polymer,webcomponents,neon-animation-runner-behavior)

```
Polymer({
    is: 'test-animation',
    behaviors: [Polymer.NeonAnimationRunnerBehavior,Polymer.NeonAnimationBehavior],
    properties: {
        opened: {
            type: Boolean
        },
        animationConfig: {
            value: function() {
                return {
                    'entry': {
                        name: 'slide-from-right-animation',
                        node: this,

                        timing: {delay: 2000, duration: 6000}
                    },
                    'exit': {
                        name: 'fade-out-animation',
                        node: this,

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    listeners: {
        'neon-animation-finish': '_onNeonAnimationFinish'
    },
    show: function() {
        this.opened = true;

        //this.cancelAnimation();
        this.playAnimation('entry');
    },
    hide: function() {
        this.opened = false;
       // this.cancelAnimation();
        this.playAnimation('exit');
    },
    _onNeonAnimationFinish: function() {
        if (!this.opened) {
            this.style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Are you able to post the markup for `test-animation`? It's possible you're not calling `hide` correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I think you made a mistake in the imported behaviors.
You are using :

-`Polymer.NeonAnimationRunnerBehavior`, which is correct since your component is *running an animation*.

-`Polymer.NeonAnimationBehavior`, which is incorrect: this behavior is meant for *creating an animation* (fade, slide, whatever you wish). You, on the other hand, want your component *to be animatable* (meaning, having a Polymer.NeonAnimationBehavior applied to it). The correct behavior for that is `Polymer.NeonAnimatableBehavior`

So you should change:

```
behaviors: [Polymer.NeonAnimationRunnerBehavior,Polymer.NeonAnimationBehavior]
```

to :

```
behaviors: [Polymer.NeonAnimationRunnerBehavior,Polymer.NeonAnimatableBehavior]
```

**Edit :**

I can confirm this was indeed the problem, as I tested this solution successfully.
However, you also have some coma and semi-colon problems in the declaration of your animation. It should be as follows :

```
    animationConfig: {
      value: function() {
        return {
          'entry': {
            name: 'slide-from-right-animation',
            node: this,
            timing: {
              delay: 2000, duration: 6000
            }
          },
          'exit': {
            name: 'fade-out-animation',
            node: this
          }
        };
      }
    }
```

Comment: So @ddobby94, did you take a look at this ?